# How to dynamically initialize an Array in JavaScript from a WebService call response

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to initialize an array in JavaScript from a WebService (asmx) response but for some reason it doesn't appear to be working. The call is made from an html page. I'm using the inArray sample from another SO post that works fine if I statically declare the array in either one of these ways:

```
var unavailableDates = new Array("26-3-2019", "25-3-2019", "24-3-2019");
var unavailableDates = ["26-3-2019", "25-3-2019", "24-3-2019"];
```

But when I construct a string with the same format and return it from a WebService call, inspecting the innerHTML I can clearly see it has the identical format but the inArray method will fail everytime to identify the value in the array.

```
 $.get(hostUri, {}, function (response) {
    var prohibitOrderDates = response.documentElement.innerHTML;
    // innerHTML returns "26-3-2019", "25-3-2019", "24-3-2019"
    var unavailableDates = new Array(prohibitOrderDates);

    function unavailable(date) {
    dmy = date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getFullYear();
    if ($.inArray(dmy, unavailableDates) === -1) {
            return [true, ""];
        } else {
          return [false, "", "Unavailable"];
        }
    }
  }).error(function (err) {
    // for debugging only
    alert(err);
  });
```

What am I missing?

Here is my WebService Method and I'm tried many variations on it to include returning a string array and a generic list of string but the result is always the same.

```
[WebMethod]
public string GetReservationInfo(string resvNo)
{
    int reservationNo = 0;
    int x = 0;
    int.TryParse(resvNo, out reservationNo);
    try
    {
        var blockedOrderDays = 4;
        var blockedDay = String.Empty;
        var noOrderDays = String.Empty;
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
        var svclient = new Marketing.Marketing_10600020PortTypeClient();
        var result = svclient.GetReservation(reservationNo);

        var details = result.Reservation.ArrivalDate;
        var arrivalDt = formatDate(details);
        while(blockedOrderDays != 0)
        {
            blockedDay = formatDate(details.AddDays(-blockedOrderDays));
            noOrderDays += blockedDay + "\"," + "\"";
            -- blockedOrderDays;
        }
        noOrderDays = noOrderDays + arrivalDt;
        return noOrderDays;
    }
    catch 
    {
        return "notonfile";
    }
}
public static string formatDate(DateTime date)
{
    var month = date.Month.ToString();
    var day = date.Day.ToString();
    var year = date.Year.ToString();
    return day + "-" + month + "-" + year;
}
```

Comment: What format is your response in?

Comment: how do you return the response, could you please post the code of the webservice?

Comment: @James - string.

Comment: Method body of webservice added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have few options here:

1) Best option IMHO: Adjust web method to return JSON encoded array. Then use JSON.parse as suggested by @James. In order to do it you will have to rewrite the GetReservationInfo to return array instead of a string and it will be automatically JSON encoded, but I may be wrong here.

2) Your current webmethod returns comma separated string with date string quoted. On JS side this looks like this: "\"26-3-2019\", \"25-3-2019\", \"24-3-2019\"". So in order to get an array of strings you have to do following:

> JSON.parse("[" + prohibitOrderDates + "]")

3) Adjust webmethod to return dates without quotes (e.g do not concat with \"). Then use prohibitOrderDates.split(',');

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use JSON to encode the response your webservice gives, and then parse it to a javascript array.  That is the easiest sensible way to do this.

But maybe this will work anyway?

```
var unavailableDates = JSON.parse(response);
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried the JSON.parse enclosing the response but for some reason it didn't work so I removed the escaped quotations and used the split function as suggested and it worked. I believe the JSON parse function will likely work as well but I think more code mod would be required to return the response more appropriately to use that method. The split function did the trick quick without much mods involved. I'll use the JSON to encode moving forward. Thank you guys!